# Read Test cases from excel in cypress

Tags: javascript, csv, testing, xlsx, cypress

I want to read the test cases from excel and run dynamically in cypress. Can anybody help me to implement this.
I am following this article but getting error:
[dynamically-generate-data-in-cypress-from-csv-xlsx](https://medium.com/@you54f/dynamically-generate-data-in-cypress-from-csv-xlsx-7805961eff55)

Comment: What is the error you're getting?